# would selenium find_elements_by_tag_name("img") capture CSS images?

Tags: html, css, selenium

I am new to web programming / selenium and I am just curious whether executing the selenium command `.find_elements_by_tag_name("img") would capture CSS images...

would it?
thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't have  tags, they are just background images in other elements. "Tag" refers specifically to the HTML element name, like "P" for `<p>` or "SCRIPT" for `<script>`

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer; how can I capture HTML and CSS images all together?

Comment: I don't think you can access the CSS images via Selenium. Why do you need to do that? Selenium should be used to make sure everything works, is clickable, visible, typable, etc. If you were testing whether or not an image existed on the server (IE, not a 404) then that's one thing, but I can't imagine another scenario in which you'd need to test functionality of a CSS background image.